# Saving nested JS Objects in cache and reloading them upon return

Tags: javascript, jquery, oop

The following is a console.log of the nested JS object that I am trying to store for later use. My current problem is that this object is lost during the facebook authentication redirect. And when I try to stringify/store to localstorage and then parseJSON, I loose the items prototype.

Can anyone think of a way to store this object so that when the page is loaded again, I can reset the `Order.current.selectedItems` to the values below? Thanks!

[image: The object I am trying to store, then reload]

Answer (score 1):

If you stringify the data, you can stash it in `window.name` then "json"-ify it back into data afterwards.

Comment: This works, but I am having problems reconstructing all of the Objects to their original prototype since all of the prototypes are lost upon stringifying. Using Localstorage has the same problem. I am trying to figure out how to reconstruct all of the nested objects manually from the standard objects returned.

Comment: Been looking for answer to that one. Not much luck.